# TypeError: render is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

I am doing a tutorial that I think might be outdated link: https://youtu.be/-edmQKcOW8s .

the tutorial was going well until I got the error :

TypeError: render is not a function
updateContextConsumer
C:/Users/Development/Desktop/STD-app/my-app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:18747

```
  18744 | {
  18745 |   ReactCurrentOwner$1.current = workInProgress;
  18746 |   setIsRendering(true);
> 18747 |   newChildren = render(newValue);
        | ^  18748 |   setIsRendering(false);
  18749 | } // React DevTools reads this flagXC   xcz.
  18750 |
```

not sure how to solve this error. please can someone help me.

Comment: We need to see some code. No one will watch a six hour long tutorial video for you to figure out what's wrong with **your** code, I'm afraid.

Comment: Please can you paste your code ? as its difficult to figure out as to what you are trying to achieve